# Does Ukrainian "звинуватити" relate to "видати"

Tags: дієслова

Does Ukrainian "звинуватити" relate to "видати" (видіти) by analogy with "кинути" -> "кидати" and "глянути" -> "поглядати".

As I understood the "d" letter fall out before "nu" suffix.

If the answer is "yes", the second question is: Does Ukrainian "вибачити" relate to "бачити"?

Comment: I suppose these are two different questions. What about the letter "з". What about "ува" absent in "кинути"? I don't really see the analogy.

Comment: @P. Vowk If I understood correctly, "з" prefix relates to ["з" preposition](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B7#Etymology_1), which means "from". I did not find "ви" prefix but I think it somehow relates to [Russian "вы"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D1%8B-#Prefix) with "out from" meaning, which is a bit like "from".

Comment: following your logic... if "vy" is a prefix, then the verb is "daty," and the original word is "vynuvatyty". what's the connection between "daty" and "vynuvatyty" then? I think there will be an answer after all, but the question lacks inner logic, I'm considering closing it. Would you probably share what dictionary you use when translating from Ukrainian into English? Some research is demanded from the askers on this site.

Comment: @P.Vowk I am talking about "з" in "звинуватити" and "ви" in "вибачити".

Comment: Let's wait for the others to answer, we'll see how it goes. As for now, it's really not clear what you are asking. I would add information from dictionaries. The question is too broad.

Comment: Maybe the right question is which morphemes are contained in the word. In the Ukrainian word "звинуватити" contain morphemes з-вин-ува-т-и-ти. Root "вин" means "guilty, accusation" and in no way connected with the root "вид" in the word "видіти" which means to "see". This is not an alternation of consonants, but different roots.

Comment: @ХристинаВороніна would you probably try to answer the question?

Answer (score 2):

You're true that -д- disappears from the end of the root in some cases:

- [гляді́ти](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=18833&page=644) ([гле́діти](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/9375-ghledity.html#show_point)) — [гля́нути](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=18843&page=645);
- [ки́дати — ки́нути](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=41524&page=1311);
- [розповіда́ти — розпові́сти́](http://sum.in.ua/s/rozpovidaty);
- etc

Never-the-less this doesn't relate to видати/видіти/винуватити. In видати "to give out", that д is not the last letter of the root, but actually the first letter of the root (e.g. давати, дати, видати, задати, надати, подати, etc). In видіти "to see" (not so often used word), that д is really the last letter of the root, but it never falls out (or at least I can't remember any cases when it does: вид, видіти, завидки, виднота, видимість, etc.). Винуватити "to blame" is derived from вина "fault/guilt", this root never has д (вина, винний, завинити, винуватити, винуватий, провина, повинність).

Вибачити "to forgive" and пробачити (the same meaning) are really etymologically related to бачити "to see" ([there is even a separate question for that](/q/2742)) — they have common root and origin. However for a modern Ukrainian speaker these words don't seem to be related (just their modern meanings "to see" and "to forgive" are so distant, that without relying onto etymological dictionary not so much people can say for sure whether these words were really related somehow ages ago or just they sound similarly due to some non-relationship-caused coincidence).

Answer (score 1):

звинуватити = to blame

видати ( to give out ) != видіти ( to see ). Видіти is sort of jargon, sub language ( usually from west Ukraine ).

кинути ( to drop, means an action that is going to happen. I'm going to drop this thing down. ).

кидати ( to drop, dropping, means the process of dropping, I was busy with dropping things down).

вибачити doesn't relate to бачити

Бачити = to see, means also the ability to see.

Вибачити = to forgive

No relation between these.

I hope this is helpful

Comment: I am not sure that "видіти" is usually from Western Ukraine. Would you probably give us proof of it? I would also like to see the dictionaries you were using when translating all those words. It could be useful for learners to get acquainted with such resources not to have to ask every question here, to be able to look for the answers themselves. -1 as for now. Your answer is all right in general. We just need more links)

Comment: Thank you for downvoting @P.Vowk
This is super motivating.

Comment: "Бачити… Вибачити… No relation between these" — while there's really almost no semantic relation (almost nothing common in meaning), but there's still etymological/morphological relation ("вибачити" is "бачити" with added "ви-" prefix; and probably these words have common origin). I'm not sure whether the question author talked about semantics or about etymology/morphology.

Comment: @podarok as soon as there are links in your answer, there'll also be my "up". I thought that explaining my minus could really be motivating (that I'm not just fooling around with up and down clicks but trying to make this domain better).

Comment: @P.Vowk
If "trying to make this domain better" means setting downvotes for the people that can contribute - than something wrong with policies or with how you understood them.
I have experience I could share, but the only proof is my own experience and my life. If you have experience to add links - use edit functionality instead of downvoting my experience. 
Sorry for being direct, but being kind means a lot. To be kind way more important than setting rough requirements for the community

Comment: @podarok I don't agree with what you are saying. This community (and stackexchange in general) has certain rules that discern it from the rest of the forums. To keep the site's content quality high enough, we need to help people follow those rules. One of the ways to do it is downvoting their answers and telling people the way to improve their posts. I am ready to upvote it once you provide at least some proofs of what you are saying. Do you want me to find those rules? Or do you probably know what I am talking about?